# Is Amalek the nephew of Leviathan?

Tags: genesis, 1-samuel, judges, genealogy, leviathan

> Genesis 36:12
>
> Esau’s son Eliphaz also had a concubine named Timna, who bore him Amalek. These were grandsons of Esau’s wife Adah.

> Genesis 36:22
>
> The sons of Lotan: Hori and Homam. Timna was Lotan’s sister.

The word "Lotan" is very similar to "Leviathan". Could it be possible that Lotan was named after Leviathan?

Comment: Possibly similar in English; not in Hebrew (one has ט while the other ת).

Comment: @DerÜbermensch They are more similar in the original Hebrew than in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "Leviathan" is a Hebrew term that appears in the Bible (psalm 104), and it is often used to refer to a large sea monster or serpent.

The word "Lotan" is also of Hebrew origin, and it appears in some ancient Near Eastern texts (non Hebrew) as the name of a serpent or dragon (The word "Lotan" appears in the Ugaritic texts and the Akkadian Epic of Gilgamesh).
Some scholars believe that the word "Lotan" may be related to the word "Leviathan," and that it may have originally referred to a similar type of mythical creature. However, it is also possible that the two words are unrelated, and that they simply have a similar sound or meaning.

In any case, Amalek was the nephew of a person named Lotan, and not Leviathan, (where in the Hebrew language they do not have the same meaning) while we cannot be sure why Lotan was named so.

On one hand, It is not certain that Lotan and his parents knew Hebrew, so it could be that Lotan is the Akkadian/Ugarit word for the Leviathan (Leviathan is a Hebrew word).

On the other hand, if you date the myths about Lotan in the Ugaritic text to be parallel to the flood, so, many years have passed since then till the birth of Lotan, and we cannot be sure how far these myths have spreaded and survived.

If the Lotan in the myths was a seven headed serpent, then, according to the Talmud, it seems that these are not the same creatures.

Comment: I wouldn't call the Leviathan an "animal".

Comment: @agarza Sorry, I studied it more and came up with a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Leviathan = לִוְיָתָן (Livyathan)**

Meaning: "serpent", a sea monster or dragon (Strongs), Job 3:8, 41:1, Ps 74:14, 104:26, Isa 27:1.

2. **Lotan =  לוֹטָן (Lotan)**

Meaning: a son of Seir from the root "lowt"; covering; Lotan, an Idumaean (Strongs), Gen 36:20, 22, 29, 1 Chron 1:38, 39.

The two words are quote different in occurrence in the Bible with different meaning and are quite unrelated.